# PHP Errors after Migrating Wordpress Site

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, serialization

After attempting to migrate our Wordpress site to the root, the page builder  theme we're using now shows the majority of the pages as blank. The page builder theme uses rows and modules with the data stored in the _postmeta table of the database. I've checked the database and the page data for the builder is still there, albeit serialized. After migrating, I did do a search and replace on the database, which I now know wasn't a good move due to the serialized data. However, I've restored the database and the site/theme files to an earlier date and the issue still persists. The site is blank! :(

I've checked the error logs for the server, and I'm noticing 3 recurring warnings starting after the migration:

**Warning 1**

```
PHP Warning:  substr() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in /hermes/waloraweb013/b1721/blu.icweb4704n/test/wp-content/themes/cutting-edge/framework/spyropress-functions.php on line 105
```

*Line 105 reads:*

```
$text = substr( $text, 0, $length );
```

**Warning 2**

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hermes/waloraweb013/b1721/blu.icweb4704n/test/wp-content/themes/cutting-edge/framework/builder/spyropress-row-functions.php on line 382
```

*The code for line 382 is:*

```
foreach ( $rows as $row_ID => $row ) {
```

**Warning 3**

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hermes/waloraweb013/b1721/blu.icweb4704n/test/wp-content/themes/cutting-edge/framework/builder/spyropress-row-functions.php on line 332
```

*Line 332 is also:*

```
foreach ( $rows as $row_ID => $row ) {
```

I need help figuring out what could've gone wrong and still be wrong after restoring the site and the database to an earlier time, and without changes in of the Lines which now have errors. Is it possible that the database is caching? I've cleared my browser cache and restarted several times to no avail.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated - we're talking about 8 months worth of work I really can't afford to lose.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The blank page is likely due to a fatal error rather than those warnings.  Temporarily, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` right after the `<?php` opening tag in your wordpress index.php file and see if you get more useful information.

Comment: Thanks for replying @drew010. Activating the error reporting showed the same 2 warnings on the page. There are also no console errors. Any other thoughts on this?